# URL Rewrite regex with apache

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file. I can generate my custom url. In my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^p/([\w-]+)/?$ awish.php?wishId=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I can use my profile page mysite.com/username with rules which is above.
My awish.php page does not work like:

> mysite.com/p/awish/43242

But it works when I call **mysite.com/p/awish/** without id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is not supporting URI `p/awish/43242`. You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^p/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?wishId=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```